# AOP programming in Bash? (Call something before bash function is  executed?)

Tags: bash, hook, aop

More than once I feel like to hook all my Bash functions with a per-execute hook/function.

Is there any solutions exists already?

Comment: See here: http://superuser.com/questions/175799/does-bash-have-a-hook-that-is-run-before-executing-a-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your exact use case, you may be able to use the `trap` command with the `DEBUG` argument.

```
trap '<your_cmd>' DEBUG
```

causes your_cmd to be executed *after* every command or line in a script.